# Как передать данные из одного окна в другое с разными доменами?

Tags: javascript

Хочу сделать что-то вроде Facebook login. Открываю popup, через `window.open`, там пользователь входит, и нужно передать access token в родительское окно, подобно тому как это происходит в facebook login.

Пробовал postMessage, но opener = null, как я понял из-за разных доменов.

Comment: может поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219003/fb-login-spawns-new-window-and-cannot-get-access-token

Comment: Про Facebook login я указал чисто для того чтобы дать понимание что я хочу сделать. Открывается окно с моим собственным авторизационным сервером. Происходит вход, а как передать токен из попапа в родительское окно я не знаю, вот и думаю в фейсбуке как то же это сделали, значит это возможно, вопрос только как )